# Fetch Google Analytics API with Python and Google2Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-analytics-api

My plan is to fetch the GA API with python3 and [google2Pandas](https://github.com/AURA199X/Google2Pandas).

My problem so far is that I don't know where to start first, when I look at the google2pandas README it looks easy but I have issues to build my own script with that and implementing the Oauth2 stuff.

What is the right way to start with these [boiler plates?](https://github.com/AURA199X/Google2Pandas/tree/master/google2pandas)

All those functions are a bit confusing to me.

What do I really need to use the analytics v4 API and fetch some simple stuff for my dashboard? Which Parameters do I have to set and how or where in the file should I do that? Another question is, do I have to use those functions in a new python file or can I go start with the _panalysis_ga.py?

It would be really helpful if you can guide me here or at least steer me in the right direction with some example.

Comment: Heya, the README file on the repo has a quickstart demo; basically, you do not need to do the OAth2 script, but you need to create a GCP account, get client keys and pass them as parameters to the google2Pandas library. did you try all of that?

Answer (score 0):

The link to the repository kind of has the answer, but appreciate it's not always clear if you've never seen it before. There is no need to do anything on the OAth2 process as the library seems to take care of that.

Use `pip` to install the google2Pandas library on your machine.

You then need to create a GCP account if you don't already have one, and follow step 1 [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-py) to get the credentials.

you can then use the Quick Demo shown on the README file of the repository (modify the query to your needs).

**EDIT**

Look into the New and Improved section of the README file as it is the most up to date one.